# Solana rent exempt account, period of exemption

Tags: rent, exemption, lamports, balance

Hey so we are all said to make rent-exempt accounts at creation time but is the rent exemption permanent?

If not, how is the top-up handled after the exemption period? Like as soon as it ends you add rent exemption lamports again? This means one would need to track all these accounts so as to add lamports when the exemption end is near.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rent exemption is guaranteed to be permanent - even in the event of a rent calculation change, they'll be grandfathered in.

Per the docs [here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/programming-model/accounts#rent-exemption):

> Note: Rest assured that, should the storage rent rate need to be increased at some point in the future, steps will be taken to ensure that accounts that are rent-exempt before the increase will remain rent-exempt afterwards